# Failed to pull backend - Please check the supported SSR features - Next.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

After updating some code, to use GraphQL instead of Data Store, my builds are failing. I have CI/CD setup in Amplify, and when I check in code it kicks off a build. I haven't added any new front-end features, other than references to amplify/api:
`import { API } from 'aws-amplify';`

Now I am getting a weird error that seems to be pointing directly to Next.js, and specifically to Server Side Rendering. However, I don't have any pages that use SSR (yet). I get the failure when I attempt to use amplify CLI to push to Amplify as well:
`amplify push`

However, if I use amplify serve, the backend is deployed successfully, and the web site runs locally, and it runs fine. The graphQL queries run fine and return data.

This is the error log from the Amplify web site, when a CI/CD build runs:

```
2023-01-21T19:43:19.800Z [INFO]:  Failed to pull the backend.
2023-01-21T19:43:19.801Z [INFO]: Learn more at: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/
2023-01-21T19:43:19.802Z [INFO]: Session Identifier: 3d5bc9be-ed87-4a9a-9bf1-f7d33021a3b3
2023-01-21T19:43:19.969Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-01-21T19:43:19.969Z [INFO]: Please check the supported SSR features to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplify-support.html#supported-unsupported-features. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. When I scrolled up from this error message, I found more explicit errors in the log. They were between "warning" messages, which made them harder to find.